# Group of symplectic matrices over the field of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, symplectic-group

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix#Complex_matrices), there are two different definitions of a "complex symplectic matrix" $M\in\mathbb{C}^{2n\times 2n}$. I am interested in the relation between the groups that follow from those two definitions.

**Definition 1:**
$$\textrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})=\left\{M\,|\,M^\top \Omega M = \Omega\right\}$$

**Definition 2:**
$$\widetilde{\textrm{Sp}}(2n,\mathbb{C}) = \left\{M\,|\,M^\dagger \Omega M = \Omega\right\}$$

where $^\top$ is transpose, $^\dagger$ is Hermitian conjugate (i.e. transpose conjugate), and $\Omega$ is the usual symplectic form with off-diagonal blocks $\pm\mathbb{I}_n$. I included the tilde just to differentiate between the two definitions.

The question: Are these two groups $\textrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ and $\widetilde{\textrm{Sp}}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ isomorphic to each other? If yes, how can one easily see it? If they are not, is there any simple (e.g. subgroup) relation between them?

Comment: They are not isomorphic. Definition 2 is not complex analytic; that group is a real Lie group, but not a complex Lie group. Definition 1 is the only complex symplectic group that I have ever seen. I don't know any applications for definition 2.

Comment: Your definition 2 produces a unitary group of signature $(n,n)$: multiplying your $\Omega$ by $i$ gives a hermitian matrix...

Comment: Unlike what you suggest, the wikipedia page mentions Definition 2 but does **not** claim it to thus define "complex symplectic matrices".

Comment: @BenMcKay I went across matrices with property 2 when looking at the following simple quantum mechanics problem: For a half-integer spin system, the time-reversal operator $\Theta$ is an antiunitary operator commuting with the Hamiltonian (a Hermitian matrix) $H$ with the additional property $\Theta^2 = -\mathbb{I}$. The usual choice is $\Theta = \Omega K$ where $K$ is complex conjucation. It follows (unless I screwed it up) that the matrix $M$ of eigenvectors of $H$ (i.e. the matrix that diagonalizes $H$) fulfills Property 2 -- it is a consequence of the presence of $K$.

Comment: @TomasBzdusek have you found a succesful explanation for this? I'm also in this topic. Have you published a paper already?

Comment: This might be useful http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/webpage/conjuage_symplectic.pdf
( they are not isomorphic )